# AdMob "Cannot find an ad network adapter" and "No ad to show" error

Tags: ios, swift, admob, firebase-admob

My app has been showing ads for months without issue, but now it never shows. My ads were cut when my app's earnings increased. Could this have anything to do with earnings? I don't see a problem in my policy center.

Even with test ids, ads don't appear. I have this problem with banner ads and interstitials ads.

Debug mode errors:

- `"Request Error: No ad to show."`
- `<Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.`

I searched for these errors but found the answers didn't fix the error.

Comment: Please include links to the articles you have tried, for instance: https://github.com/kmcgill88/admob_flutter/issues/63

Answer (score 0):

Add Your Google AdMob ads.txt in website.
Set Up your APP-ADS.TXT And add it on Meta Tags

Comment: Thanks but i added app-ads.txt file.

Comment: Whilst good advice, you should include links back to the relevant documentation to support this response.